# React Native doesn't rerun componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a list of toucheable items, clicking in any of them will take you to a detail screen.

The detail screen fetches data from the server in componentWillMount().

When I click on the first item, the detailscreen is displayed with the correct data. Then going back to the list and clicking on another item, the detailscreen shows the first items data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `componentDidUpdate` and do the things from there.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(prevProps!==this.props){
     //do the same as your componentDidMount
  }
}
```

`componentDidMount` only triggers the first time that specific component is rendered, to get the new datas you have to use `componentDidUpdate`